# The keep the files which have same name with different extensions in cureent directory and move remaining files to new director.y

Tags: bash, shell

```
I have files as given below 

PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.11.52.30.390.00.sac..dsp                          
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.11.52.30.390.10.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.11.52.30.390.10.sac..dsp                          
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.11.53.37.380.00.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.11.53.37.380.00.sac..dsp                          
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.11.53.37.380.10.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.11.53.37.380.10.sac..dsp                          
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.00.35.240.00.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.00.35.240.10.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.10.52.780.00.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.10.52.780.10.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.21.58.140.00.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.21.58.140.10.sac.
```

I want to move files to another directory which don't have similar file names with extension. From above-given files, I want to below-given files to new directory since they don't have similar file names with extension

```
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.00.35.240.00.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.00.35.240.10.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.10.52.780.00.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.10.52.780.10.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.21.58.140.00.sac.                              
PALK.BHZ.2012.04.11.12.21.58.140.10.sac. 


for file in *.sac.; do 
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    [ ! -e "${file%%.*}..dsp" ] && mv "$file" IIPALK/allsac
done
```

Comment: Get a list of all of your dsp files with grep, truncate the .dsp off, add both the new string and origninal dsp string to an array. Once you have all of those, just loop through your full extension list and only look at those which don't appear in your array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for f in *sac.; do same=("${f%.*}".*); [ "${#same[@]}" -eq 1 ] && mv "$f" /home/newtst ; done
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer for future readers (not in comments, you can [edit] your answer)